# How can I have each of my tile objects be initiate with an empty arraylist that I can add things to later?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I am trying to implement a board game in java, and I am currently working on the game board.  The game board has 37 hex shaped tiles.  Each of these can hold buildings, several Creatures, and a marker that shows who owns it.

I have 37 instances of each tile, and now I am unsure as to how I can have each tile hold a collection(array, array list, linked list, whatever) on each tile.  As a player moves there creatures through the board, I will be taking things from the array on that tile and adding it to a different array on a different tile.

My first instinct is to put several array lists in the constructor for my Tile class, but I don't believe this is possible.   any ideas?

This is how I have defined my Tile class so far if curious:

```
public class Tile {
    //neighbours of each tile
    public Tile n0;
    public Tile n1;
    public Tile n2;
    public Tile n3;
    public Tile n4;
    public Tile n5;

    public int owner = 0;

    public Tile (Terrain ter, int owned){
        owner = owned;
    }
}
```

Edit:

I want to do something like this with my constructor:

```
public Tile (Terrain ter, int owned, ArrayList<Creature> creatureList){
        owner = owned; 
}
```

BUT I'm not sure if this is legal, or this makes sense.  Will doing something like this allow me to have an array list associate with each Tile instance I define?  Or is there a better way?  I don't know if it needs to be defined in the parameters of the constructor or not.

Comment: do you mean to add ArrayList parameters, or, creating the lists in the constructor? Showing an example of your idea might help us tell you whether that's a good idea, as well as helping you figure out the solution yourself. I think if you write the code in the first place, it will help you see what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to have an array holding each of tile objects like this, because you are sure the size will fixed as per your board.

```
Tile[] tiles = new Tiles[37];
```

Then have each of the tile objects initialized with an empty list

```
for(int i=0; i<tiles.length;i++)
{
    tiles[i] = new ArrayList();
}
```

This way, you dont have to create 37 object in your main class and also at the same time give you flexibility to add any number of items to each individual tile.

The complete class refactored would look like this:

```
public class Tiles {
    //collection of tiles
    Tile[] tiles = new Tiles[37];


   // in the constructor initialize each individual tile with an arraylist
    public Tiles (){

        for(int i=0; i<tiles.length;i++)
        {
            tiles[i] = new ArrayList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I thought I already accepted this!  Thank you for your help!